# Error with the output of Camera Calibration OPENCV 3.2 with C++ Visual Studio 2015. Cant save output value

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, c++14, camera-calibration

i am getting an error when using opencv camera calibration. When i debug my code, it just open the webcam not show the camera calibration value output in Folder Location.
i am using opencv 3.2 with VS 15
 My code:

```
 #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/aruco.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const float calibrationSquareDimension = 0.01905f; //meters
const float arucoSquareDimension = 0.1016f; //meters
const Size chessboardDimensions = Size(9,6);

void createArucoMarkers()
{
    Mat outputMarker;

    Ptr<aruco::Dictionary> markerDictionary = aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME::DICT_4X4_50);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        aruco::drawMarker(markerDictionary, i, 500, outputMarker, 1);
        ostringstream convert;
        string imageName = "4x4Marker_";
        convert << imageName << i << ".jpg";
        imwrite(convert.str(), outputMarker);



    }
}
void createKnownBoardPosition(Size boardsize, float squareEdgeLength, vector<Point3f>& corners)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < boardsize.height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardsize.width; j++)
        {
            corners.push_back(Point3f(j * squareEdgeLength, i * squareEdgeLength, 0.0f));
        }
    }
}

void getchessboardcorners(vector<Mat> images, vector<vector<Point2f>>& allfoundcorners, bool showresults = false)
{
    for (vector<Mat>::iterator iter = images.begin(); iter != images.end(); iter++)
    {
        vector<Point2f> pointBuf;
        bool found = findChessboardCorners(*iter, Size(9, 6), pointBuf, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

        if (found)
        {
            allfoundcorners.push_back(pointBuf);

        }
        if (showresults)
        {
            drawChessboardCorners(*iter, Size(9, 6), pointBuf, found);
            imshow("Looking for Corners", *iter);
            waitKey(0);
        }
    }
}

void cameraCalibration(vector<Mat> calibrationImages, Size boardSize, float squareEdgeLength, Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distanceCoefficients)
{
    vector<vector<Point2f>> checkerboardImageSpacePoints;
    getchessboardcorners(calibrationImages, checkerboardImageSpacePoints, false);
    vector<vector<Point3f>> worldSpaceCornerPoints(1);

    createKnownBoardPosition(boardSize, squareEdgeLength, worldSpaceCornerPoints[0]);
    worldSpaceCornerPoints.resize(checkerboardImageSpacePoints.size(), worldSpaceCornerPoints[0]);

    vector<Mat> rVectors, tVectors;
    distanceCoefficients = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);

    calibrateCamera(worldSpaceCornerPoints, checkerboardImageSpacePoints, boardSize, cameraMatrix, distanceCoefficients, rVectors, tVectors );

}
bool saveCameraCalibration(string name, Mat cameraMatrix, Mat distanceCoefficients)
{
    ofstream outStream(name);
    if (outStream)
    {
        uint16_t rows = cameraMatrix.rows;
        uint16_t columns = cameraMatrix.cols;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                double value = cameraMatrix.at<double>(r, c);
                outStream << value << endl;

            }
        }

        rows = distanceCoefficients.rows;
        columns = distanceCoefficients.cols;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                double value = cameraMatrix.at<double>(r, c);
                outStream << value << endl;

            }

        }

        outStream.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    Mat frame;
    Mat drawToFrame;

    Mat cameraMatrix = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);

    Mat distanceCoefficients;

    vector<Mat> savedImages;

    vector<vector<Point2f>> markerCorners, rejectedCandidates;

    VideoCapture vid(0);

    if (!vid.isOpened())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int framesPersecond = 20;
    namedWindow("Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true)
    {
        if (!vid.read(frame))
            break;

        vector<Vec2f> foundPoints;
        bool found = false;

        found = findChessboardCorners(frame, chessboardDimensions, foundPoints, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE );
        frame.copyTo(drawToFrame);
        drawChessboardCorners(drawToFrame, chessboardDimensions, foundPoints, found);
        if (found)
            imshow("Webcam", drawToFrame);
        else
            imshow("Webcam", frame);
        char character = waitKey(1000 / framesPersecond);

        switch (character)
        {
        case ' ':
            //saving image
            if(found)
            {
                Mat temp;
                frame.copyTo(temp);
                savedImages.push_back(temp);

            }
            break;
        case 13:
            //start calibration
            if (savedImages.size() > 15)
            {
                cameraCalibration(savedImages, chessboardDimensions, calibrationSquareDimension, cameraMatrix, distanceCoefficients);
                saveCameraCalibration("CameraCalibration", cameraMatrix, distanceCoefficients);
            }

            break;
        case 27:
            //exit
            return 0;
            break;

        }

    }
    return 0;

}
```